# Stacking JPanels in the same direction

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I would like to stack JPanels on in the same direction.
I've searched this and can't find anything. The results that show up mean "overlap".

This is what I mean:

[image]

I would like to stack the second JPanel underneath the first. When using: `add(BorderLayout.NORTH)` on both layouts it overlaps them.

I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: seems like ..., search for java + swing + accordion

Comment: See [How to Use `BoxLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) & [How to Use `GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) if the GUI needs a group of (possibly different sized) components stacked vertically (or horizontally).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I usually code something specific like this, I like to use the **GridLayout**, and set it to 2 Rows and 1 Column like so.

```
  //this will go with the boiler plate
 this.setlayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
```

This should fix the problem of the two JPanels, and you can always add more to the rows if needed.